# Way to trigger FancyBox by clicking on <div> rather then <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am having issues with my CMS - its seems it doesn't like having an `<a>` tag within an `<a>` tag as my Fancy Box 2 set up has.

To test I replaced:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#popup">
```

with

```
<div class="fancybox" href="#popup">
```

This solved my original issue, but because its not legitimate mark up and breaks a lot of the other code.

Would anyone know a correct way to modified Fancy Box 2 to do this?

Comment: Don't you need some javascript to open the fancybox ? `$("a#image").fancybox();`

Comment: @JFK sorry - havent had time to put it into practice yet. Will let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always bind fancybox to any element other than the `<a>` tag with a valid (HTML5) structure and functionality, using the special fancybox's `data-*` attributes like :

```
<div class="fancybox" data-fancybox-href="#popup">open fancybox</div>
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ6mV/)</kbd>